# Text disappearing when adjusting height of TopAppBar on Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I am trying to adjust the height of the `TopAppBar` in an Android app, using `Jetpack Compose`. When I update the Modifier of the TopAppBar to adjust to `height = 150.dp`, I see that the bar has a larger height but the text and navigation icon button disappear.  When I don't do anything to the height, the text appears fine.

```
Scaffold( 
   topBar =  { TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Hello",
                        style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 24.sp)

                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                   IconButton(onClick = {
                     navController.popBackStack()
                     }) {
                   
                     Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, null, tint = Color.White)
                  }
                   
                    
                },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Black,
                    titleContentColor = Color.White
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp)
            )
}
) {...}
```

I used the Layout Inspector on Android Studio to see where the text and icon going. In the Layout Insepctor, I see that both elements are still present, they just seem to be hidden or not showing for some reason. Here is what I see in the Layout Insepctor. [Text in TopAppBar not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3kFb.png)

Comment: The TopAppBarLayout has a fixed height. The height modifier just change the surface that contains the TopAppBarLayout.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way I change the height of the AppBar, then? I basically would like there to be 150.dp of padding above the title text.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        LargeTopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = "Hello",
                    color=Color.White,
                    style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 24.sp)
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                },) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, null, tint = Color.White)
                }
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = Color.Black,
                titleContentColor = Color.White, navigationIconContentColor = Color.White
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp)
        )
    }
) {paddingValues -> paddingValues}
```

[image]

try to run before invalidate catch and restart.

Comment: Nothing shows up still with these changes you suggested.

Comment: I have put my output it's working fine in my system. invalided catch and restart I think it's work.

Comment: Why are there two "Hello"s that show up?